Refining a regular space to make it non-regular
This question has been made after this other question has been answered. I was reading the beginning of the section $3$ of this paper and, from what I understand, given a regular topological space $(X, \tau)$ that has a non-open dense subset $D$, the topology on $X$ generated by $\tau \cup \{D\}$ isn't regular. It cites Exercise I.8.20 on page 140 of Bourbaki's General Topology, Part 1. The problem is that I have no access to read it. I wondered why this resulting topology is non-regular. I also wondered if the topology on $X$ generated by $\tau \cup \{X \setminus D\}$ isn't regular neither.

Given a regular topological space $(X, \tau)$ that has a non-open dense subset $D$, the topology on $X$ generated by $\tau \cup \{D\}$ isn't regular.
In this new topology ($\tau'$), $X \setminus D$ is closed. Now, let $x \in D$ such that $x$ is not an interior point of $D$ in $\tau$ ($x$ exists, because $D$ isn't open in $\tau$). Then, the only option to separate $x$ from $X \setminus D$ in $\tau'$ is $D$. Now, since $D$ is dense in $\tau$, every open neighborhood of $X \setminus D$ in $\tau'$ has non-empty intersection with $D$. Therefore, $X\setminus D$ and $x$ can't be separated by disjoint neighborhoods in $\tau'$, so it isn't regular.
Another topology on $X$ that refines $\tau$ and isn't regular is the one generated by $\tau \cup \{X \setminus D\}$.
In this new topology ($\tau'$), $D$ is closed. Now, let $x \in X \setminus D$. Since $D$ is dense in $\tau$, the only option to consider to separate $x$ from $D$ in $\tau'$ is $X\setminus D$. But now, as $D$ isn't open in $\tau$, there exists $y \in D$ such that every neighborhood of $y$ in $\tau'$ has non-empty intersection with $X \setminus D$. Therefore, $D$ and $x$ can't be separated by disjoint neighborhoods in this new topology, so it isn't regular.
